# Get document library size (REST API)

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-rest-api

Does anybody know if there's any property on the document libraries that tells me the size of it? Or how many of the items that's folders and how many thats's files.

I know I can query each library directly and filter the folders from the items, but I would like to avoid doing that due to a rather large amount of call I'd be making.

Right now I'm using this endpoint, which gives me info of all libraries in the site:

```
/_api/web/lists?$select=Title,LastItemUserModifiedDate,ItemCount
```

I have tried adding a `size` property (Also a `ItemSize` property) but that does not seem to exist.